# OpenCV namedWindow background color

Tags: python, opencv

I am using namedWindows to display result images in OpenCV in fullscreen. If the image aspect ratio does not match the screen aspect ratio the residual area is filled with an ugly grey. Is there any simple option to change this background color? (Except cropping the image, or overlaying it to a matching black Mat).
I am working in Python on Linux.

Thanks

EDIT:
here an example code showing the problem (remember to change image path):

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import numpy as np
import cv2

#test image fullscreen

img = cv2.imread('./bilder/DSC_0825.JPG',cv2.IMREAD_UNCHANGED)
cv2.namedWindow('display',cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.setWindowProperty("display",cv2.WND_PROP_FULLSCREEN,cv2.cv.CV_WINDOW_FULLSCREEN)
cv2.imshow('display',img)
cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows
```

Here a screen shot of the output:
[Is there a standard option to change the grey bars to e.g. black ones?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i2m63.jpg)

Comment: I can't really reproduce this using Windows, can you please provide screentshots and code?

Comment: If you know the _optimal_ size (where you don't get gray borders), you can create a background image with wanted color, and copy your image in it's center. Or use `copyMakeBorder` to add a border with a given color to your images. Or use a some GUI library to have full control, since HighGui is intended mainly for debugging purposes.